# Notifications are pulling as empty when I apply .where("user.askerUserId", "==", auth.currentUser.uid)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to pass a filter that shows notifications for the user but the data keeps coming back blank when I console log it. I think the issue may be a mistake in how I'm making the comparison but I'm not sure. I had the same issue with how the timestamp was called from the database but that is fixed. I'm wondering if this could be the same issue

The issue is on line 33.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Popper from "@material-ui/core/Popper";
import NotificationsIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
import "../Style/Header.css";
import db, { auth } from "../firebase";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    border: "1px solid",
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    zIndex: "10",
  },
}));

export default function SimplePopper() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(anchorEl ? null : event.currentTarget);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? "simple-popper" : undefined;

  useEffect(() => {
    let mounted = true;
    let unsub = db
      .collection("notifications")
      .where("user.askerUserId", "==", auth.currentUser.uid)
      .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        if (mounted) {
          setNotifications(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              content: doc.data().content,
            }))
          );
        }
      });
    return () => {
      unsub();
    };
  }, []);
  console.log(notifications);

  return (
    <div className="header__icon">
      <NotificationsIcon
        aria-describedby={id}
        type="button"
        onClick={handleClick}
      />
      <Popper id={id} open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl} style={{ zIndex: 100 }}>
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <ul className="notifications">
            {notifications.map((notification) => (
              <li key={notification.id}>{notification.content}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Popper>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that because I was making making a comparison with the filter I had to create a composite index in the firestore settings. If you're getting this issue you should see an error like the following appear:

> FirebaseError: The query requires an index. That index is currently
> building and cannot be used yet.

**It should have a link for you to click** that will take you to your firebase console and allow for it to automatically create an index. Once I did this my snapshot worked.